# How to optimize download speeds from AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

We keep user-specific downloadable files on AWS S3 buckets in N.Virginia region. Our clients download the files from these buckets all over the world. Files size ranges from 1-20 GB. For larger files, clients in non-US location face and complain about slow downloads or interrupted downloads. How can we optimize these downloads?

We are thinking about the following approaches:

1. Accelerated downloads (higher costs)
2. use of CloudFront CDN with S3 origin (Since our downloads are of different files, each file being downloaded just once or twice, will CDN help since, for 1st time, it will fetch data from US bucket only)
3. Use of akamai as CDN (same concern as of CloudFront, only thing is we have a better price deal with akamai at org level)
4. Depending on the user's location  (we know where the download will happen), we can keep the file in the specific bucket which was created at that aws region.

So, I want recommendations in terms of cost+download speed. Which may be a better option to explore further?

Comment: 3 has additional cost (3 - Transfer out from S3 to Akamai) and 4 will give you slow speed, There are more POPS than AWS regions.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Are these private objects, or publicly accessible?

Comment: @John These are private objects.

Comment: How are your users authenticating to access the files at the moment? If you move to Amazon CloudFront, you will likely need to implement a different authentication method.

Comment: we are using presigned urls with some validity.

Answer (score 3):

As each file will only be downloaded a few times, you won't benefit from CloudFront's caching, because the likelihood that the download requests all hit the same CloudFront node and that this node hasn't evicted the file from its cache yet, are probably near zero, especially for such large files.

On the other hand you gain something else by using CloudFront or [S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) (the latter one being essentially the same as the first one without caching): The requests enter AWS' network already at the edge, so you can avoid using congested networks from the location of the user to the location of your S3 bucket, which is usually the main reason for slow and interrupted downloads.

Storing the data depending on the users location would improve the situation as well, although CloudFront edge locations are usually closer to a user than the next AWS region with S3. Another reason for not distributing the files to different S3 buckets depending on the users location is the management overhead: You need to manage multiple S3 buckets, store each file in the correct bucket and point each user to the correct bucket. While storing could be simplified by using [S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) (you could use a filter to only replicate objects to a specific target bucket meant for this bucket), the overhead with managing multiple endpoints for multiple customers remains. Also while you state that you know the location of the customers, what happens if a customer does change its location and suddenly wants to download an object which is now stored on the other side of the world? You'd have the same problem again.

In your situation I'd probably choose option 2 and set up CloudFront in front of S3. I'd prefer CloudFront over S3 Transfer Acceleration, as it gives you more flexibility: You can use your own domain with HTTPS, you can later on reconfigure origins when the location of the files changes, etc. Depending on how far you want to go you could even combine that with S3 replication and have multiple origins for your CloudFront distribution to direct requests for different files to S3 buckets in different regions.

Which solution to choose depends on your use case and constraints. One constraint seems to be cost for you, another one could for example be the [maximum file size of 20GB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html) supported by CloudFront, if you have files to distribute larger than that.

Comment: Our download links are valid for a short span only. So user's location change won't come into the picture.

Anyways, thanks for the insight. Will post again if I have any further doubt.

Comment: Agreed. Amazon CloudFront would be the simplest option to begin with, and is likely to solve the download problems (even for infrequently accessed objects). I would suggest you create the CloudFront distribution, then try it with the users who have complained the most, to see whether it fixes things.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, It did help us in our testing. We are planning to go ahead with this approach. 1 more suggestion if you can give, How to handle requests from users of Russia where CloudFront is blocked?

Comment: I'm not familiar with countries being blocked from CloudFront. I did a web search and saw that S3 might also be blocked? If that's the case, there's nothing you can do since there is nowhere to redirect them. If they _can_ reach S3, then you could probably do some geo-routing in Route 53 to send some geos (eg Russia) to S3 and the rest to CloudFront.